# Firestore Query over Map keys Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have some products stored in different storages. Something like this: So I would have 4 products in storage "A25" and 3 products in storage "A40".

```
Product{

   placesDeposited:{
                 A25:4,
                 A40:3
   }
}
```

I tried this:

```
 Query query = db.collection("products").whereArrayContains("placesDeposited",storageID)
```

I want to put this Query in a recyclerView

I want to have a query that return all products that are stored in storage "A25" in firestore.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working the way you expect?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the console that shows the document you expect to match this query?  What you're showing now isn't very clear.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.  Please respond with @AlexMamo